# Distribution upgrade failing behind proxy

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, proxy

I am running Xubuntu 14.04LTS and I want to upgrade to 16.04LTS.

I use CNTLM as a local proxy to pass through a corporate ISA/WebSense proxy.

This works fine for Internet access, apt-get update, apt-get upgrade and apt-get install (or Synaptic for any of these).

However when I try apt-get dist-upgrade it says there is no upgrade available and if I use 'do-release-upgrade' it fails due to not receiving a response from the proxy.

There is clearly a proxy problem but searching through Google and /etc/apt/ I cannot seem to identify it. Can anyone let me know the difference between how apt-get handles update, upgrade and dist-upgrade?